# How render an LCD-like display in Android using ExtJS?

Tags: html, css, extjs4, extjs4.2

I am building a web application using ExtJS 4.2. There's a part in the web app where I display certain information in an LCD-like screen.

I achieved this using a `textarea` where I used ⬛ and ⬜ to assemble a screen display. I set the font size to 1px, I set the text area's width to 240 pixels. But as it turns out, the last 10-20 pixels would be bumped down to the next line. This is evident when I viewed the page on a Windows and an Android Tablet.

Here's the sample output viewed on a Mac where the 240 pixels are displayed in a row:

[image]

And here's the same sample output viewed on an Android Tablet:

[image]

And as evidently seen, the last handful of pixels are bumped into the next line, and the display is ruined.

It is clear that even if we set the width of the text area to 240 pixels, it does *not* fit 240 1-pixel characters.

We also tried to set the `letter-spacing` to -1px. Since the character size is 1px, we expected no display, as seen from this screenshot when viewed on a Mac:

[image]

However, when viewed from the Android Tablet, we see a sliced display:

[image]

And it implies that the 1px font width is actually larger than what it is.

Does anyone know how to make a pixel perfect LCD-like display using JavaScript/HTML5?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ext.draw.* packages
Especially sprites like rect and path may work for you.

Underlying tech is SVG so you might want to google "LCD SVG " etc

Guide :
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/guide/drawing

Examples:

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/example/draw/Rotate Text.html